# when installing airflow, it occurs: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, airflow

os: centos7.6
python 3.8
occur error:
Collecting airflow
Using cached airflow-0.6.tar.gz (1.2 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Answer (score 1):

maybe this help

```
python -m pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools   
pip install airflow
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply saying the build tool `setup.py` fails to build from source.
I am not so technical in the aspect of building from source, so I can't tell you exactly what to do with your `.tar.gz` file to make it all right.

If you have `pip` installed on the machine (which I assume you do), then simply type:
`pip install apache-airflow`
The long version:
`python3 -m pip install apache-airflow`

If you intend to use `celery` together with Apache Airflow, I suggest:
`python3 -m pip install apache-airflow[celery]` for full installation.

Refer to the [documentation of Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.1/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) for more info.